# Windows 7, notebook backlight turn on and off

Tags: c#, c++, windows, lcd, backlight

I have seen topics about changing notebook's screen brightness, but the thing that actually is needed now is to turn on and off the backlight itself.

By it i mean, that if backlight is turned off, then you can see image on-screen of notebook by using a bright light source, like a flashlight, pointed at screen.

Some notebooks have the special button to toggle the backlight, but some do not. For like a month i cant find a way to toggle the backlight programmaticaly.

Does any of you know, how to do that, if possible, at worst case even using vendor-specific API?